# NHibernate with string primary key and relationships

Tags: .net, nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I've have just been stumped with this problem for an hour and I annoyingly found the problem eventually.

**THE CIRCUMSTANCES**

I have a table which users a string as a primary key, this table has various many to one and many to many relationships all off this primary key.

When searching for multiple items from the table all relationships were brought back. However whenever I tried to get the object by the primary key (string) it was not bringing back any relationships, they were always set to 0.

**THE PARTIAL SOLUTION**

So I looked into my logs to see what the SQL was doing and that was returning the correct results. So I tried various things in all sorts of random ways and eventually worked out it was. The case of the string being passed into the get method was not EXACTLY the same case as it was in the database, so when it tried to match up the relationship items with the main entity it was finding nothing **(Or at least NHIbernate wasn't because as I stated above the SQL was actually returning the correct results)**

**THE REAL SOLUTION**

Has anyone else come across this? If so how do you tell NHibernate to ignore case when matching SQL results to the entity? It is silly because it worked perfectly well before now all of a sudden it has started to pay attention to the case of the string.

Comment: Can you post your mapping files?

Comment: Is the casing correct for newly added items? Have you updated NHibernate lately? SQL is usually case sensitive, however using "LIKE" statements they can be both depending on dialect, but you don't want to use that when resolving relations.

Answer (score 4):

I have the exact same situation on a ref table in my DB. I mapped the schema file the same way you did. In code, when I query for the record by Primary Key, I do the following using an instance of the NHibernate ISession:

```
return session.Get<T>(id);
```

In this statement, T is the type you are querying for, and id is the string id you are looking for (the Primary Key)

Here is an example of my mapping file:

```
    <class name="Merchant" table="T__MERCHANT">
        <id name="MerchantId" column="MERCHANT_ID" type="string">
            <generator class="assigned" />
        </id>

        <property name="MerchantStatusId" column="MERCHANT_STATUS_ID" type="Char" not-null="true" length="1" />
        <property name="MerchantStatusName" column="MERCHANT_STATUS_NAME" type="string" length="50" />
        <property name="MerchantName" column="NAME" type="string" not-null="true" length="50" />
 </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

And my C# code looks like this:

```
public Merchant GetMerchantById(string id)
{
     return session.Get<Merchant>(id);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For consistency sake, please revise this:

```
<joined-subclass name="JohnHarmanLtd.Web.FineArtCompany.Models.Book, App_Code.tqeub3fb, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null">
```

More specifically "**App_Code.tqeub3fb**". It looks like you're using temporary assemblies from an ASP.NET Website as part of the mapping for NHibernate?

Move your Business Entities out into their own library so the assembly name is always the same.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my workaround (and it is a workaround; I am dealing with a in-place DB which was designed poorly IMO).

Originally sourced from: https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?f=25&t=979685&view=previous

Here is my custom string class (in VB):

```
Imports NHibernate.UserTypes
Imports NHibernate.Type
Imports NHibernate.SqlTypes

Public Class CaseInsensitiveStringType
    Inherits AbstractStringType

    ' Methods
    Public Sub New()
        MyBase.New(New StringSqlType)
    End Sub

    Public Sub New(ByVal sqlType As StringSqlType)
        MyBase.New(sqlType)
    End Sub


    ' Properties
    Public Overrides ReadOnly Property Name As String
        Get
            Return "InsensitiveString"
        End Get
    End Property

    Public Overrides Function IsEqual(ByVal x As Object, ByVal y As Object) As Boolean
        Return MyBase.IsEqual(x, y) OrElse (x IsNot Nothing AndAlso y IsNot Nothing AndAlso String.Equals(x, y, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
    End Function

    Public Overrides Function GetHashCode(ByVal x As Object, ByVal entityMode As NHibernate.EntityMode, ByVal factory As NHibernate.Engine.ISessionFactoryImplementor) As Integer
        Return MyBase.GetHashCode(x.ToString().Trim().ToUpperInvariant(), entityMode, factory)
    End Function
End Class
```

And I use FluentNhibernate, so here is what the mapping looks like (only apply to Id fields):

```
Id(Function(x) x.Id).GeneratedBy.Assigned().CustomType(Of CaseInsensitiveStringType)()
```

And that was that; my associations started to be populated properly again.

Again, it is MUCH better to design your DB correctly using int/GUID PKs rather than strings, but if you have to, this is a decent way of "fixing" NHibernate.

Comment: Add in .Trim() to x and y in the String.Equals if you think you might need to worry about that.

Answer (score 0):

There is no option for this but you can achieve the same using QBE

```
Example.create(parent).ignoreCase()
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand your problem :

- when you query by the PK with Get method, the object returned has no value for the relationships
- when you query by another kind of query (an example will be useful), the relationships are not empty ?