# How to use string keys in (fluent) NHibernate

Tags: c#, .net, database, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I am working with brownfield database that uses strings as primary keys. 
Using **Fluent NHibernate** with **Sqlite** (in-memory provider for unit testing) and **SQL Server 2005**.

I have the following entity:

```
public class Entity
{
    public virtual DateTime TimeStamp { get; set; }

    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
}
```

With this mapping:

```
public class EntityMap : ClassMap<Entity>
{
    public EntityMap()
    {
        Map(_ => _.TimeStamp);
        Id(_ => _.Name).CustomType("AnsiString");
    }
}
```

However it does not work saying `NHibernate.TypeMismatchException : Provided id of the wrong type. Expected: System.Int32, got System.String`

How make this work? Also, is there any good documentation about fluent nhibernate available?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thx for links, though they neither are new for me nor contain anything related to my question :) I was not able to find anything about string keys there. Also I would like to start with explicit mapping.

Comment: This is discussed in this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/411825/nhibernate-with-string-primary-key-and-relationships

Comment: @krystanhonour not exactly. Also that question has no accepted answer. If you can recognize the answer there could you repost it here and get vote-up and my appreciation? Thx.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you are using strings as your primary keys you'll probably have to do something like this:

```
public class EntityMap : ClassMap<Entity>
{
    public EntityMap()
    {
        Id(x => x.Name).GeneratedBy.Assigned();
        Map(x => x.TimeStamp);
    }
}
```

From the nhibernate documentation:

> 5.1.4.7. Assigned Identifiers
>
> If you want the application to assign identifiers (as opposed to
>   having NHibernate generate them), you may use the assigned generator.
>   This special generator will use the identifier value already assigned
>   to the object's identifier property. Be very careful when using this
>   feature to assign keys with business meaning (almost always a terrible
>   design decision).
>
> Due to its inherent nature, entities that use this generator cannot be
>   saved via the ISession's SaveOrUpdate() method. Instead you have to
>   explicitly specify to NHibernate if the object should be saved or
>   updated by calling either the Save() or Update() method of the
>   ISession.

Also here is a related article. It is a bit dated but still applies to your situation:

http://groups.google.com/group/fluent-nhibernate/browse_thread/thread/6c9620b7c5bb7ca8